# Android obfuscation issue with Retrofit migrating to Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) 8 and Java 17

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, obfuscation, android-r8

## The problem

I encounter an obfuscation issue migrating from Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) 7.4.2 to 8.2 and Java 11 to 17: `Unable to create @Body converter for class package.api.data.device.DevicesBody (parameter #1) for method a.a`

Everything is working well except API calls. I use Retrofit 2 with Kotlin Serialization (kotlinx.serialization).

```
// Retrofit
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0" // Retrofit
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.2" // OkHttp Logging Interceptor

// Kotlin Serialization
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.4.1" // Kotlin Serialization JSON
implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter:0.8.0" // Retrofit 2 Kotlin Serialization Converter
```

It's working disabling obfuscation `minifyEnabled false` or adding the obfuscation rule `-keep class ** { *; }`, but of course it's not an acceptable solution.

## My code

```
private val json = kotlinx.serialization.json.Json {
    prettyPrint = true
    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
    explicitNulls = false
}
private val contentType =  "application/json".toMediaType()
private val retrofit: Retrofit by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(json.asConverterFactory(contentType))
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .client(httpClient)
        .build()
}

@Keep
@Serializable
data class DevicesBody(
    @SerialName("dh_info")
    val dhInfo: DhInfo
)

@Keep
@Serializable
data class DhInfo(
    @SerialName("type")
    val type: String,
    @SerialName("value")
    val value: String
)

@POST("devices")
suspend fun postDevice(@Body requestBody: DevicesBody): Response<DevicesResponse>
```

## The exception

```
MESSAGE: Unable to create @Body converter for class {my_package}.api.data.device.DevicesBody (parameter #1) for method a.a
STACKTRACE:
    [retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:54),
    retrofit2.Utils.parameterError(Utils.java:60),
    retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseParameterAnnotation(RequestFactory.java:781),
    retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseParameter(RequestFactory.java:325),
    retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.build(RequestFactory.java:206),
    retrofit2.RequestFactory.parseAnnotations(RequestFactory.java:67),
    retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:26),
    retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:202),
    retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:160),
    java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006),
    $Proxy5.a(Unknown Source), g0.j0.invokeSuspend(SourceFile:1),
    g0.j0.invoke(SourceFile:1), c.g.a(SourceFile:0),
    g0.k0.invokeSuspend(SourceFile:0),
    g0.k0.invoke(SourceFile:1),
    kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow.collectSafely(Builders.kt:61),
    kotlinx.coroutines.flow.AbstractFlow.collect(Flow.kt:230),
```

## Changes for AGP 8.2

For the migration to Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) 8.2 (including Java 17), I made these changes:

- On `app/build.gradle`:

```
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0"
    }
    
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
```

- On `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip
```

- On `gradle.properties`:

```
# Enable generation of the BuildConfig class
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
# Disable on-transitive R classes
android.nonTransitiveRClass=false
# Disable R classes with non-final fields
android.nonFinalResIds=false
```

- On `app/proguard-rules.pro`:

```
# Keep generic signature of Call, Response (R8 full mode strips signatures from non-kept items).
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking interface retrofit2.Call
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.Response

# With R8 full mode generic signatures are stripped for classes that are not
# kept. Suspend functions are wrapped in continuations where the type argument
# is used.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
```

## The solution

On `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
...
# API data package (for Retrofit2)
-keep class {my_package}.api.data.** { *; }
-keep public enum {my_package}.api.data.** { *; }
...
# Retrofit2
# Keep generic signature of Call, Response (R8 full mode strips signatures from non-kept items).
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking interface retrofit2.Call
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.Response
# With R8 full mode generic signatures are stripped for classes that are not kept. Suspend functions
# are wrapped in continuations where the type argument is used.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
```

Comment: Please check https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/main/compatibility-faq.md#retrofit to see if all the suggested rules has been added.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a compatibility issue. The retrofit version you're using doesn't support Gradle 8.0.
Based on the information on Retrofit's Github repo, the latest Gradle version they support is [7.6.2](https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/3922) and this was done just 5 days ago. However, Retrofit version 2.9.0 was released in 2020. I believe a new version will be released in the coming months.

Comment: The pull request you have linked is just about upgrading the gradle version used for compiling retrofit itself. This does not automatically mean the compiled plugin can be only used in gradle up to version 7.6.2.

Comment: Well, Gradle 8.0 is new and it has breaking changes. If you check Gradle's official site you'll see they advised developers to upgrade to 7.6.x before upgrading to 8.0.

Comment: There is no 7.5.x or 7.6.x version of Android Gradle plugin. The latest version 7.x.x is 7.4.2 (see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle). So this means we're stuck on version 7.4.2 until Retrofit provides a new compatible release. Unfortunately Retrofit no longer produced any releases since 2020...